# Excluding junit-vintage-engine says "'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests"

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I support a platform and parent pom used by a couple hundred services.  We've been doing a gradual shift from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. Initially, we wanted to allow both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests, so we're including junit-vintage-engine as a dependency, and that is working fine.  When I run the build on a sample service, it runs all of the unit tests, which consists of one JUnit 4 test and several other tests, all JUnit 5.

This is what I see in the normal case:

```
15:07:46 [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ PlatformPilotMs ---
15:07:46 [INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
15:07:47 [INFO] 
15:07:47 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
15:07:47 [INFO]  T E S T S
15:07:47 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm now trying to take the next step to remove the junit-vintage-engine by default, allowing individual project poms to specify it, if they can't get off of JUnit 4 yet.

So, in the parent pom,  I added an exclusion for junit-vintage-engine on the one dependency that it comes from, and I also removed an explicit dependency for it.  I changed the version of that parent pom so I could compare the results.

When the service is using the old pom, I can run "mvn dependency:tree", and I find "junit-vintage-engine" in the dependencies.  When the service is using the new pom, I don't see "junit-vintage-engine" anywhere in the tree output.

However, when I then run the build with it using the new parent pom, I see this:

```
15:11:10 [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ PlatformPilotMs ---
15:11:10 [INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
15:11:10 [INFO] 
15:11:10 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
15:11:10 [INFO]  T E S T S
15:11:10 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
15:11:12 [ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
15:11:12 [INFO] 
15:11:12 [INFO] Results:
15:11:12 [INFO] 
15:11:12 [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

This is perplexing.  I suppose it was sort of successful.  I expected this to not find the one JUnit 4 test.  That certainly worked.  However, it also failed to find any of the JUnit 5 tests.

What might I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you any engine in your dependencies... also why using an older version of maven-surefire-plugin(current: 3.0.0)...

Comment: junit-jupiter-engine, junit-platform-engine, and junit-platform-suite-engine . I'll try version 3.0.0 in a few hours.

Comment: Ah, excellent. that worked. Moving forward.